# Cell fracture causing cube instead of original object

Tags: physics

I'm trying to fracture two objects and ultimately smash them together.  However, the green hand (first object I am trying to fracture) turns into a fractured cube when I use cell fracture on it.  I converted it from a curve to mesh.  Is this an easy fix?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

This is the cell fracture window:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The mesh is not watertight (manifold)

Cell fracture is having some problem with your mesh because it cannot easily recognize an enclosed volume to work with. As you can see in the image sequence below there are some vertices that, despite looking apparently connected, they are not.

The meshes created by converting an extruded curve are currently made this way.

[image]

The solution in this specific case would be to run thr **Remove doubles** command form the *Vertices* sub-menu (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> while in edit mode with all the vertices selected).

---

Here's a comparison between reults after and before merging the overlapping vertices:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks!  Unfortunately though it still causes weird problems when I use cell fracture after.  I've added a screenshot in my question.

Comment: There should also be something in the operator's settings, because the shown example was done with your hand after just removing the 592 doubles. Could you show them?

Comment: Sorry how do I find operator settings?  I tried to google it but couldn't find anything

Comment: I mean the panel that pops up just after pressing the Cell fracture button.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response...I've posted the cell fracture panel

Comment: Mmmh, no, I don't see nothing strange there. Try with this file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1596/ and let me know if your result is still the same. Mine, with those settings, can be found in the layer 11. Are you using 2.77 official version? Is the pc running out of ram during the process?

Comment: Thanks Carlo I managed to get the results I wanted by using the grease pencil and then checking the debug boolean box in the cell fracture panel.  Then I used the boolean-difference modifier to individually remove unwanted deformities.  Probably not the best way, but it did the job.  I am using 2.76.

Comment: Actually though, your version fragmented much better.  And I wasn't able to get the solid pieces to separate the way yours did (they wouldn't move if I selected a fragment and tried to move it).  I'm definitely going to use your .blend!

Comment: Hahah! Glad it helped in some way. It's a pity the mistery didn't get solved. Did you tried with a different mesh (e.g a simple cube)? Is it giving the same behaviour?

Comment: Ya too bad not sure what I was doing something wrong, but your blend could help shed light on fragmenting complex objects for others.  I have only ever fragmented cubes in the past using youtube tutorials and this site...it was tricky, but it always fragmented properly.

Comment: Sorry one more question...do you know how I could fracture just part of the object?  Like the index finger specifically?

Comment: Cell Fracture work on the whole object. I would cut the finger (knofe tool) and then fracture it as a separate object (select faces, press "p" and then fill holes).

Comment: Thanks finally got it to work!  Also, remesh can help when fill gives an error for anyone who has a hard time sealing all faces.