# Blender Cell Fracture results in cube

Tags: add-on, unity

I'm trying to create a broken sphere to import into Unity for a project. I am using Cell Fracture to do this, but when I create a new UV Sphere and run cell facture on it, it gives me this instead of a broken sphere

[image: cell facture]

These are my settings (If it has anything to do with it)

[image: cell facture settings]

I saw [this question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/cell-fracture-causing-cube-instead-of-original-object) which had the same issue as me, but the solution did not work. [Here](https://github.com/squarednob/crack_it/tree/official_2.8) is the download link where I got it from which I got from this forum [here](https://developer.blender.org/T61901). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it's now fixed with the Blender release candidate 2 ...

Comment: @Muad that is the version I am using, but I have able to fix the issue by getting an older version of blender.